# Kubernetes rolling Update

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Blue Green Deployment is the best technique  to Reduce Downtime and Risk for rolling update in kubernetes? If No , then suggest something better and if yes then from where i will get configuration for blue green deployment ?

Comment: This question is pretty vague.  The details of a deployment strategy should be very carefully considered.  Kubernetes comes with a rolling update algorithm.  If you don't want a rolling update, you can build your own custom blue-green style update process with `kubectl`.

Answer (score 2):

For rolling update you don't need to do additional configuration changes other than the changes you need to do in the next version of replication controller. You can find this [demo](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/update-demo//) to try rolling update in kubernetes. However the issue in blue green deployment is that the consistency is not guaranteed at the moment of rolling update. You may see both old version and new version of pods at the same time. If you want to do a consistent update of a replication controller with an introduced down time, you can try kubernetes [replace](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_replace/) command with cascade flag.